# Convert http://localhost/post.php?id=4 to http://localhost/post/4 with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, post

i'd like to convert **localhost/post.php?id=4** to **localhost/post/4** with .htaccess, my currently code is:

```html
# Activate RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

#HIDE .PHP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
 
#locahost/username
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ usuario.php?usuario=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (;|<|>|’|”|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\./\.\. [OR]
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.[a-z0-9] [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

#EXTRA
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

And if it's possible also convert **localhost/username** to **localhost/user/username**
Thanks :)

Comment: not a good idea but how about `/id/4`?

Comment: @Beginner I don't think using `id` is any better, I mean I am speaking on @Jean's behalf but using id is quite generic meaning if there are other items on the site which use id's will be difficult to work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a rewrite rule for that

`RewriteRule ^/post/([0-9]+)$ /post.php?id=$1 [L]`

and

`RewriteCond /user/%{REQUEST_URI} -d`

`RewriteCond /user/%{REQUEST_URI} -f`

`RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /user/$1 [L]`

The first one simply redirects  /post/X  to /post.php?id=X

The seocnd one checks if  /user/[requested URI] exists as a file or directory then if it does, forwards to that particular file

**NOTE** the second one will conflict if a user has the same name as another directory in the root of the site and effectively prevent anyone from accessing that folder from your site -- so I would not use the second one.